# pass data in listview on button clicked

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

i want to pass the data of the itemselected to another page. The below code is working as expected.

```
private void inProgress_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var surveyTapped = (SurveyList)e.SelectedItem;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new StartSurvey(surveyTapped.vchar_Title, surveyTapped.int_SurveyID, surveyTapped.int_UserSurveyID));            
        }
```

But i have 2 button in the listview and i have to add on clicked on those buttons

[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhWWT.png)

```
private void resume_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //How and what should i implement in order to pass the data 
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean, the rows in listview contains two buttons, when you click on button you want to send the data to other page which you want to navigate to?

Comment: Yes sir, thats what i want

Comment: Can you attach your project to cloud and let me download so that i can help you out?

Comment: Sorry Sir, my project is very big.... tell me what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i did that worked perfectly for me. i Used a commandparameter to pass the value. This is what i did in the listview

```
<Button Text="Resume" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="resume_ButtonClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```

and onclicked event i gave the button a reference to the listview.

```
private void resume_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var menuItem = sender as Button;
            var selectedItem = menuItem.CommandParameter as SurveyList; 
            Navigation.PushAsync(new StartSurvey(selectedItem.vchar_Title, selectedItem.int_SurveyID, selectedItem.int_UserSurveyID));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Binding is a saviour here.

If you are going with Event oriented approach, try following code:

```
    private void resume_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var selectedItem = (SurveyList)LISTVIEW.SelectedItem; // where LISTVIEW is the name of the listview.
        //Other actions
    }
```

Comment: i am getting Null value

Comment: I found the reason. if i click on the directly on the button it shows null value and if i select listview first and the click on the button i get the value

Answer (score 1):

I was a ble to catch a passed value through a button like this.

```
<Button  Clicked="delBtn_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding customerId}" x:Name="delBtn" Text="Delivered" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White"></Button>

private void delBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  var ListItem = sender as Button;
  var currentItem = ListItem.CommandParameter.ToString();
  DisplayAlert("Alert", currentItem, "Ok");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I created a button in ListView of xaml file

```
<Button Text="Submit" Clicked="btn_clicked" CommandParamter={Binding .}/>
```

Then we need to pass the data onclick of button

```
var data = (ModelName)((Button)sender).CommandParameter;

await Navigation.PushAsync(new AnotherPageName(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this suggestion.

While adding Buttons to listview rows add them with unique "id" property, this way you would know which button is clicked and it lies on which row.

It would be like ->
row 0 - Buttons id could be with 01,02
row 1- Buttons could be with 10,11
so on..

So when you click the button you would know which button is clicked and where does it lie.

When you know the listview row index, you can get the data from the itemsource property of the list at that index or use the collection you used to bind the data.

Now you have the data and you can pass the same you have done in first case.

here is the property I am talking about.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.id?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Element_Id